# Problems with event function binding in backbone.js app

Tags: backbone.js

```
$(function(){
  window.Placements = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#app"),
    events: {
      "submit form": "updatePlacement"
    },
    updatePlacement: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('foo');
    }
  });
  window.App = new Placements;
})
```

Running results in:

`TypeError: Result of expression '$(this.el).delegate' [undefined] is not a function.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using jquery 1.3.2 but backbone requires a later version (no version number is mentioned in the docs)

Comment: Backbone lists jQuery 1.4.2 in it's "Downloads & Dependencies" section.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you are setting `el: $("#app"),` and then you try to get again `$(this.el)` while in `this.el` you already have the HTML object `$(#app)`. Try to put `el: '#app'` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a typo in you events object:

event types should be first:

submit form instead of form submit

Comment: You're right, I've changed this but I still get the same error message

Comment: Have you tried with an initialize method : _.bindAll(this, 'render') ?

Comment: Tried that just now but it doesn't make any difference